# Wrapping result of the_terms in a span with a class of the term name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, front-end

I'm using the following function to return a list of custom post types, with `the_terms` showing a taxonomy term.

```
function projectCards() {
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'rneh_projects', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo '<ul>';
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<li class="project-card d-1of3 cf">';
          the_terms( $post->ID, 'rneh_status', ' ', ' ' );
          echo '<p><a href="' . get_post_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
          the_terms( $post->ID, 'rneh_author', ' ', ' , ' );
        echo '</li>';
      endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

On the face of it this does what I want it to do, but then in trying to wrap

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'rneh_status', ' ', ' ' );
```

in a span, like

```
echo '<span>' . the_terms( $post->ID, 'rneh_status', ' ', ' ' ) . '</span>';
```

so I can target it for styling, the output places the taxonomy term outside of the span, like this.

```
<a href="http://localhost/ne-heritage/research/ongoing/" rel="tag">Ongoing</a>
<span></span>
```

How do I get the output to show the term inside the span and add a class with the term name to it, or, add a class of the term name to the a href already wrapping the term name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking in the WordPress world, functions prefixed with `the_` will output results immediately. Functions prefixed with `get_` will return the results without outputting them.

The function [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) can be used to achieve the desired results. Here's a complete function that's essentially a wrapper for `get_the_terms()` with a little bit of extra formatting:

```
/**
 * Outputs a list of terms with special formatting
 * 
 * @param $post_id string|int ID for post
 * @param $taxonomy_slug string taxonomy name
 * @param $separator string separator for terms
 */
function wpse251476_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy_slug, $separator = ' ' ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy_slug );
    $separator = sprintf( '<span class="term-sep">%1$s</span>', esc_html( $separator ) );

    // Bail if there are no terms.
    if ( ! $terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $links = array();

    // Wrap each term link in a span and give the span the class name of the term's slug.
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $links[] = sprintf( '<span class="%1$s"><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
            esc_attr( $term->slug ),
            esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
            esc_html( $term->name )
        );
    } 

    // Output the terms.
    ?>
    <div class="term-list <?php echo esc_attr( __( $taxonomy_slug, 'text-domain' ) ); ?>">
        <?php echo implode( $separator, $links ); ?>
    </div><?php
}
```

**Usage examples based on original code:**

```
wpse251476_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'rneh_status', ' ' );
```

and

```
wpse251476_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'rneh_author', ' , ' );
```

Comment: That's done the job, thanks for the explanation and examples! Just wondering, is there any specific reasoning behind the function name?

Comment: Glad that did the trick! Feel free to rename the function. This naming convention is used to ensure that the function name is unique. `wpse` (WordPress StackExchange) then `251476`, the id of this question.